# How many trading days are there in the U.S stock market for the year 2016?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

Half days are also counted.

I am not able to find websites that provide the information for the past years.

Comment: https://www.nyse.com/markets/hours-calendars ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

- 252 in 2016
- 251 in 2017

[Trading Days on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trading_day)

For the calculation method, check out:
[Calculation for trading days in a year](https://tradingsim.com/blog/trading-days-in-a-year/)